# How to refer to two previous elements / tags / classes with LESS

Tags: css, class, less

I have this html markup:

```
<figure class="about half">
    <figcaption class="head_section">
        <h3>About</h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

and this LESS set up:

```
 figure {
    //some style

    &.half {
      width: 48%;
    }

    figcaption {

      h3 {

        .about & & {
          // what i need to do but isn't working
        }
      }
    }

    &.about {

      h3 {
        // some style i have which is working
      }
    }
  }
```

So, my question is how to refer two previus class of `figure.about` so as not to be out of style `h3`. I hope that is clear... Much thx.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say "two previous classes" and also "not to be out of style".

Comment: i want to add some style for h3 depend on `figure.about` class, so i need to set up style for two previously elements - in that case for `figure`... look at the comments in code :)

Comment: The code you mention as "is working" is the correct (and only) way to do a _nesting_ and get what you want. The `&` should be purely viewed as a string replacement for the full nested structure. So there is no way to access just the `figure` element from within the `figcaption` nesting that you currently have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here, as you haven't supplied a desired css output. The idea I kinda managed to extract from your question would be a css that looks like this:

```
figure {
  /* some style */
}
figure.half {
  width: 48%;
}
figure.about figcaption h3 {
  /* what i need to do but isn't working */
}
```

is this correct?

Here is a way to get this to work with `&`:

```
figure {
    /* some style */
    &.half {
        width: 48%;
    }
}
figcaption {
    h3 {
        .about & {
            /* what i need to do but isn't working */
        }
    }
}
```

The thing here is that the `&` returns the "path" for all nesting levels above, so you need to construct the nesting rules with exactly the ones you want to use (in our case I moved the `figcaption` out of the `figure` rule). So this should give you the selector appearance you want. However, the structure of the nested rules will often depend on the way you want to use `@variable` inheritance and scope referencing and in some cases it just makes it hard to build the structural selector exactly the way you want, but then there will almost never be the need for including the whole html structure in your selector - and just as in your case `figure.about h3` will work just as well as `figure.about figcaption h3`, as you probably will not add more `h3` elements into the figure container.

Comment: so, there will a be problem if i have this figure in global container, f.e. body ... :)

Comment: when i will have this `figure` in f.e. `#main_container` block this rule does't take `#main_container` as global path?

Comment: you shouldn't put the `figcaption` ruleset inside any other ruleset if you want `&` to work the way you want it. You probably don't need to nest it inside the main container. Depend's on what css exactly you want to assign with this selector. You can also define a more general class selector in the main container and then at the end overwrite it, but this really depends on how you plan to structure the css and style the page.