# What is the difference between ampersand and double ampersand in Less?

Tags: css, reactjs, less

I am trying to write Less in the context of React.

The following code works:

```
.rt-tr-group .rt-tr:hover .rt-td {
    color: #fff;

    &:first-child { /* notice single ampersand */
        border-left: 2px solid #007aff;
    }
}
```

This code also works:

```
.rt-tr-group .rt-tr:hover .rt-td {
    color: #fff;
}
.rt-tr-group .rt-tr:hover .rt-td:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid #007aff;
}
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
.rt-tr-group .rt-tr:hover .rt-td {
    color: #fff;

    &&:first-child { /* notice double ampersand */
        border-left: 2px solid #007aff;
    }
}
```

I have seen the double ampersand used elsewhere in the codebase, so && does something.  Could someone please explain the difference to me?

Comment: Are you certain that the rest of the codebase is SASS and not LESS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228089/double-ampersand-in-less

Comment: Turnip you are right, it is probably LESS.  Thank you for pointing this out and for the link.  This must be why I couldn't find anything googling.

Comment: http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-multiple-

Answer (score 2):

The double ampersand you've seen might be `& + &` or `& ~ &`, not `&&`, as to the best of my knowledge the latter does nothing in Sass.

Using `& + &` will allow you to target an adjacent sibling of the same selector, for example this SCSS:

```
.btn {
  ...
  & + & {
    margin-left: 15px;
    background: firebrick;
  }
}
```

...will compile to this CSS:

```
.btn {
  ...
}
.btn + .btn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: firebrick;
}
```

Read more about the double ampersand [here at Team Treehouse](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/sass-tip-double-ampersand-selector).

Comment: As another user pointed out, I am using LESS and not SASS.  Thank you for your answer, though.  I read through the article and it make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is redundant to the basic logical operator `AND` in nearly every popular programming language, while the single `&` is used specifically in SASS for connecting CSS selectors.

Connecting, or to be more precise in the use case of SASS: Concatenating selectors is very different from combining two conditionals in a logical sense.

Read further:
https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-operators/ and https://javascript.info/logical-operators

Comment: As another user pointed out, I am using LESS and not SASS, so I updated my question.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be to increase specificity: `.thing.thing` is higher than just `.thing`

Comment: I removed important as it is not relevant to this code.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ok, great! If that's the case I'm certain that `&&` is intended to make the rule stronger. I've used this myself, especially when you need to override third party styles.